# If $M$ is an $A$-module via $\varphi\colon A\to\operatorname{End}(M)$, $\mathrm{coker}(\varphi)\otimes M$ is projective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I have a brief passage I don't understand. Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $A$ is an $R$-algebra, which is projective and finitely generated as an $R$-module. Let $M$ be a progenerator for $A$, so $M$ is projective and finitely generated as an $A$-module.

Let $\varphi\colon A\to\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ be the canonical map, and $C$ the cokernel. The composition
$$
M\xrightarrow{m\mapsto 1\otimes m}\operatorname{End}_R(M)\otimes_A M\xrightarrow{f\otimes m\mapsto f(m)} M
$$
is the identity. So $\varphi\otimes_A 1_M$ is a split injection of $R$-modules.

Since $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ is a projective $R$-module and $M$ is a projective $A$-module, $C\otimes_A M$ is a projective $R$-module.

I don't understand this last sentence. I know that the tensor product of projective modules is projective, but we're looking at $C=\operatorname{End}_R(M)/\varphi(A)$, not $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$, and it's not clear that $C$ is projective?

Comment: $C \otimes_A M$ is isomorphic to the cokernel of $\varphi \otimes_A 1_M$ (since $C$ is the cokernel of $\varphi$, and since the tensor product is right-exact). But I think that the cokernel of a split injection of projective $R$-modules is projective. (Is this true? If so, then you are done.)